# PHP не выводит результат выполнения запроса к MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть выборка MySQL. Запрос срабатывает, возвращает циферку. Всё хорошо, но вот при выводе в php он выдаёт `Resource id #6`, так вроде же отображаются массивы.

```
$query = "SELECT
            COUNT(`sms_send_certificate`)
          FROM
            $userstable
          WHERE
            `sms_send_certificate` = 1";
$sms_counter_2 = mysql_query ($query, $db) or die("you have trouble");
print "sms по сертификатам: ".$sms_counter_2;
```

Или почему так отображается?
Как вывести именно циферку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `mysql_query()` возвращает дескриптор результирующей таблицы. Чтобы получить ответ необходимо воспользоваться одной из функций чтения результата, например, `mysql_result()`

```
$query = "SELECT
            COUNT(`sms_send_certificate`)
          FROM
            $userstable
          WHERE
            `sms_send_certificate` = 1";
$sms_counter_2 = mysql_query ($query, $db) or die("you have trouble");

print "sms по сертификатам: ".mysql_result($sms_counter_2, 0, 0);
```

Однако, расширение mysql в настоящий момент признано устаревшем и исключено из PHP 7, вместо него лучше воспользоваться расширением mysqli или PDO

```
try {
  $pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
    'root',
    '',
    [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

  $query = "SELECT
              COUNT(`sms_send_certificate`) AS total
            FROM
              $userstable
            WHERE
              `sms_send_certificate` = 1";
  $sms = $pdo->query($query);

  $result = $sms->fetch();
  echo "sms по сертификатам: ".$result['total'];
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение и помощь. Заработало!